# Editing a User's Likes on Facebook

Tags: facebook, mobile

I've been looking at the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) to find some way to edit a user's Likes (that is, add or remove items from https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/).  The API doesn't say anything about it specifically, but does say this:

> You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs above.

Where above, one of the connection URLs is the aforementioned https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes link.  However, there's no documentation for the PROFILE_ID/likes post, and whenever I try to post it returns the error "invalid post_id".

I assume this is because to like something, you post a request to POST_ID/likes.  It's a bit inconsistent.  What I'm trying to do is get the user's profile to add a Page to their likes (by posting using the page's id as an "id" parameter in the post body).  However, it seems like there's just no way to edit user's likes.

At the end of the day, I just want to allow a user to click a button in my application (mobile device application, not a web app) and have them add our Facebook page into their list of pages, and I've found no way of doing that short of presenting our page to them and making them click on the "Like" button manually.  Many other things are supported without showing the Facebook website, like posting to their wall or making albums, but I can't find anything to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I can't.  Not in the way I want to anyway.